# pip install -r <file> causes "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ..." error

Tags: pip, django-cms, requirements.txt

I'm trying to install dependencies for my project in a new virtualenv.

The requirements are contained in a file (`requirements.txt`) containing the output of a `pip freeze`.

Here is its content :

```
dj-database-url==0.3.0
Django==1.8.3
django-classy-tags==0.6.2
django-cms==3.1.2
django-reversion==1.8.7
django-sekizai==0.8.2
Django-Select2==4.3.1
django-treebeard==3.0
djangocms-admin-style==0.2.7
djangocms-column==1.5
djangocms-file==0.1
djangocms-flash==0.2.0
djangocms-googlemap==0.3
djangocms-inherit==0.1
djangocms-installer==0.7.9
djangocms-link==1.6.2
djangocms-picture==0.1
djangocms-style==1.5
djangocms-teaser==0.1
djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.5.4.dev1
djangocms-video==0.1
html5lib==0.999999
Pillow==2.9.0
pytz==2015.4
six==1.9.0
tzlocal==1.2
wheel==0.24.0
```

Some dependencies where installed with `djangocms-installer` (A tool to generate a **djangocms** project). Then I made the `pip freeze` to generate the **requirements.txt**>

But why when I try to start a new virtualenv to work on an other computer, do I get the following Error at the end of my output when I run `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

```
Collecting djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.5.4.dev1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.5.4.dev1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20)) (from versions: 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0b1, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3)
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external djangocms-text-ckeditor to allow).
No matching distribution found for djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.5.4.dev1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
```

How could I fix this?

I already retried with `--allow-external`, `--allow-all-external` and `--allow-unverified` parameters but the error is still here.

Comment: There is no 2.5.4.dev1 release on github or on pypi. Those flags won't help either.

Comment: You're right, the last version seems to be 2.5.3, but how did djangocms-installer installed the 2.5.4? How is it possible then?

Comment: Maybe it was removed?

Comment: Someone on IRC gave me this link : https://github.com/divio/djangocms-text-ckeditor/commit/c01905c18eb69b0da324e6d234cd8724d72a2996 . I assume djangocms-installer installs at least this one package from github and not through pip.

Comment: I'm seeing this though https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-installer/blob/develop/djangocms_installer/config/data.py#L81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally replaced `djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.5.4.dev1` with the github link (`git+git://github.com/divio/djangocms-text-ckeditor.git`).

And it works!